# What exactly are "levels" in polyline encoding/decoding?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, android-maps-v2, polyline, google-polyline, android-maps-utils

What are "levels" in polyline encoding/decoding, and exactly how do they relate to map zoom levels in [Google Maps API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) or [Android Maps API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/)?

The only description I can find is from the [Interactive Polyline Encoder Utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility):

> Polylines in Google Maps are formed as a set of latitude/longitude pairs. In addition, for each vertex (location) in an encoded polyline, a level can be specified indicating that the location should appear on that level and any level higher (i.e. any decrease in zoom.). If a location does not appear on a given level, then the line will go from the last visible location to the next visible location. Note that the first and last locations must be Level 3 points, otherwise the polyline won't display on all levels.

Does "Level 3" correspond to a zoom level of 3 in the Google Maps API v3 or Android Maps API v2?

Here's what a zoom level of 3 looks like in the Google Maps API v3 (no polyline is displayed - this is simply to illustrate what the "zoom level = 3" looks like):

[image]

Should a "Level 3" point be displayed if we zoom out one step further, to zoom Level 2?

[image]

The quote:

> Note that the first and last locations must be Level 3 points, otherwise the polyline won't display on all levels.

...seems to indicate that Level 3 points should be displayed on all levels, including zoom levels 2, 1, and 0.

I'm wondering if the statement:

> ...a level can be specified indicating that the location should appear on that level and any level higher (i.e. any **decrease** in zoom.)

...should actually be:

> ...a level can be specified indicating that the location should appear on that level and any level higher (i.e. any **increase** in zoom.)

"decrease in zoom" doesn't seem correct, because Level 18 (very zoomed in) points would be rendered on Level 3 (very zoomed out).

"increase in zoom" seems to generally make sense (you'd render a Level 3 zoomed out point also when you zoom in to Level 18 - in other words, you add detail as you zoom in closer to the map) - however, it seems to contradict the statement that Level 3 points should be rendered at lower zoom levels 2, 1, and 0.

On Android, the open-source [android-maps-utils library](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) includes a method to [decode polylines](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.java#L433), but it doesn't handle levels, so I can't tell if there is a readily-available mapping to Android Maps API v2 zoom levels.

Can anyone provide clarity on this?

Comment: I wonder where did you write the "encoded polyline" in your code. I can't see the code at all.

Comment: @wf9a5m75 There isn't any encoded polyine in the Javascript code or displayed on the map - I was using these screenshtos simply to illustrate what a particular zoom level looks like on Google Maps.  Sorry if that wasn't clear - I'll add a note in the question about this.

Answer (score 0):

Levels are an obsolete feature. They controlled whether points were visible at certain zoom levels. They were a significant feature of Google Maps API v2, but you should ignore them now; Google Maps API v3 does it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

zoom level defines the resolution of the current view.

zoom level

- 0: to encompass the entire earth
- 1: World
- 5: Landmass/continent
- 10:City
- 15: Streets
- 20: Buildings

"zoom=12" isused in below exapmle

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.714728,-73.998672&zoom=12&size=400x400&key=YOUR_API_KEY&signature=YOUR_SIGNATURE